# How did Bathory overpower the goddess?

Tags: castlevania

In *Castlevania: Nocturne*, the so-called Vampire Messiah, Erzsébet Bathory, is said to have extraordinary powers, even relative to most vampires, due to having drunk the blood of the Egyptian goddess of war, Sekhmet.

More than simply having the powers of Sekhmet, drinking Sekhmet's blood seems to have made her Sekhmet in a very real sense, since she talks like Sekhmet almost as much as she talks like the typical vampire portrayal of Bathory, and her right-hand woman is a former priestess of Sekhmet.

Among these powers seem to be near immunity to any magic or physical force that Richter, Maria, or Tera can summon up, powerful telekinesis, and the power to blot out the sun. Even Olrox, a very powerful vampire himself and one who is unintimidated by the Belmonts or the Speakers, believes that it would be folly for him to attempt to take on Bathory.

That naturally raises the question: if Sekhmet had all these powers, how did a relatively ordinary vampire, like Erzsébet Bathory once was, overpower her, drink her blood, and presumably, in some sense, kill her?

Comment: Although, I do have to recognize that her seeming to *be* Sekhmet in a sense beyond simply having (some of?) her powers could just be delusions of grandeur. After all, she claims to have been given sacrifices of virgins in ancient times, when in the real world people were more likely to get drunk than perform human sacrifices at the festivals of Sekhmet, and she refers to the moon as her sister when she is talking about Ra as her father, when the moon god Khonsu was *male* and not Sekhmet's sibling at all.

Comment: Either she caught the goddess and drank her blood while she was asleep (in all Sekhmet myths she can get drunk and that is how Ra catches her and removes some of her power https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yygW6psCIM4 ) or it is the other way around: Bathory is just the latest name of the vampire that Ancient Egyptians worshipped as goddess Sekhmet.

Answer (score -1):

Vampires are typically depicted as growing more powerful over time. They consume more and more people and theirs souls (depending on the work) which makes them change powerfully over time. Gods in various works are often depicted as losing their powers over time due to lack of worshippers and the changing awareness of people in the world. It could be these two things crossed and she was powerful enough in the moment to defeat and drink her or she tricked and deceived her into a moment of vulnerability.

If she took in the soul of Sekhmet then she is Sekhmet essentially to a degree which she seems to state herself.

Comment: I don't really see this answering the question. You've identified how it *could* have happened, but not how it happened.